# How to Add, Build and Run existing files onto Xcode C++ Project Command Line

Tags: xcode, project

I am trying to add an existing folder to a project on Xcode. I want to run it on C++ OS Command line tool. I have added the cpp and hpp files on my project. On the Contacts folder, it includes a csv file and I have also included it on my project. The problem is that the program compiles and runs but it does not show any output of the contacts I was expecting to see. 
Is there anything I need to do right?

Thanks for the help.

[Contacts folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oye28.png)

[Project on Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sawwx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project as a Command Line Tool and using the same code called on main. Then try Activate Console command: Cmd+Shift+C or in the Top menu: View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console, then run your project Cmd+Shift+R or the play button shortcut on xCode.

[image: New Command Line Project]